# Paperjs and Brackets

Tags: paperjs, adobe-brackets

Is there any way to make paperscript work in Adobe Brackets?

It's my first time using paperjs and the paperscript script doesn't work.

Basically the text inside the script is not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking but I'd like to make a few points in hopes these will help you.

1. You must write your paperscript inside script tag in your html document, if you try to link it from external .js file it won't work because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).
2. Brackets live preview feature doesn't support javascript of any kind to my knowledge (haven't used that editor for 6 months so this might be outdated information).